# How to hide NavController & AppBarConfiguration in a fragment & activity

Tags: java, android, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I'm using a navigation graph in my Android app (Java) and have set up a NavController & AppBarConfiguration in my home activity. This is how I have it set up:

```
public class Activity extends BaseActivity {
    NavController navController;
    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityBinding activityBinding;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
        activityBinding = ActivityBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = activityBinding.getRoot();
        setContentView(view);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        navController = Navigation.findNavController(Activity.this, R.id.fragment);

        appBarConfiguration =
                new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph()).build();

        setupActionBar(navController, appBarConfiguration);

        activityBinding.bottomBar.setOnItemSelectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.mainFragment:
                        navController.navigate(R.id.mainFragment);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.secondFragment:
                        navController.navigate(R.id.secondFragment);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.thirdFragment:
                        navController.navigate(R.id.thirdFragment);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupActionBar(NavController navController,
                                AppBarConfiguration appBarConfig) {
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfig);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment), appBarConfiguration);
    }
}
```

I want the NavController & AppBarConfiguration to be hidden to allow for fullscreen visibility in one fragment & one activity. For my fragment, I've tried this solution:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ActionBar supportActionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) requireActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    if (supportActionBar != null)
        supportActionBar.hide();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    ActionBar supportActionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) requireActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    if (supportActionBar != null)
        supportActionBar.show();
}
```

And this solution:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

And this solution:

```
getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

None of these have worked. Does anyone know how to properly show a full screen when using a NavController & AppBarConfiguration?

Solution:
As suggested, I added this to my home activity:

```
public void setBottombarVisibility(int visibility){
    activityBinding.bottomBar.setVisibility(visibility);
}
```

And I have the Fragment where I want the nav to disappear extend this BaseFragment:

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    protected int isBottomBarVisible = View.GONE;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Activity act = getActivity();
        if (act instanceof Activity) ((Activity) act).setBottombarVisibility(isBottomBarVisible);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    }
}
```

Nav is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently, I came across same situation for fab and toolbar.
I created a BaseFragment () class and I let all my fragments extended from this.
In BaseFragment, declared two variables one for fab's visibility and other for toolbar.

```
    BaseFragment () {

     protected int isBottombarVisible = 
     View.Visible;
     //inside oncreateView
      Activity activity = 
      getRequireActivity() //whatever 
      //the java method to get activity 
       //inside fragment 
      
      activity
     .setBottomBarVisibility
     (isBottombarVisible) 
     //define this method in your main 
     // activity class 
    }
```

Inside MainActivity (wherever fragment reside)

```
    public setBottombarVisibility(int
    visibility) {
    binding.toolbar = visibility
    }
```

Now, inside fragment which was extended from BaseFragment () , override above variable

```
    class Loginfragment() extends 
    BaseFragment() {
    override int isBottombarVisible = 
    View.Gone
    }
```

I tried to type above code as much as possible in java..
For kotlin refer to link
https://github.com/vivekgupta4Git/TacklingNephrotic

Comment: I wasn't sure how to override the isBottomVisible variable in Java like you're able to do in Kotlin, so I tried just having the Fragment in which I want the nav gone be the only fragment to extend the base fragment. That way I could just set it to GONE in the base fragment. Unfortunately it didn't work for me.

Comment: public void setBottombarVisibility(int visibility){
    visibility = activityBinding.bottomBar.getVisibility();
}//you never set the visibility ,try changing this line to  activityBinding.bottombar.setVisibility(visibility) or w/e the java way

Comment: Oversight on my part. That fixed it. :)