# Hide action bar immediately when open android app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-actionbar

After research in goole, I can hide action bar but the current result is the action bar still show few seconds before open MainActivity. You can refer in the gif below.

My question is can we hide action bar immediately when launch app?

Here's my [source code](https://github.com/nguyenvantrai2011/Android-Hide-Action-Bar.git)

[image]

Comment: Hide it always or do you want to show it later?

Comment: @cmak I need hide it alway when app running

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73293015/15754377

Comment: @TraiNguyen if youdon't want any bar, just remove it from the main xml

Comment: @cmak I already removed it in the xml, you can take a look my source code above

Comment: @VivekGupta you can see in my gif, I can hide the action bar in activity but my expected is hide action bar immediately when launch app

Comment: @TraiNguyen it's still in activity layout https://github.com/nguyenvantrai2011/Android-Hide-Action-Bar/blob/e9a0608b58b218a5823dc410eb57f7f95cb3c420/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml#L9

Comment: @cmak that's app bar layout, not action bar. Notice my mouse cursor in gif image, the action bar is the back bar at bottom screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change theme like below

```
    <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    </style>
```

In AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
     android:name=".MainActivity"
     android:exported="true"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And the result:

[image]

I also commit new source code to [HERE](https://github.com/nguyenvantrai2011/Android-Hide-Action-Bar) if anyone needed