# How to hide action bar properly?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I have an activity and a few fragments in it, and I have an action bar that I need to be visible all the time except for the case when I open `MyTestFragment`, so when I open this fragment I need my action bar to be hidden.

As my Activity is `AppCompatActivity`, I tried to call this method (from Activity) in order to hide an actionBar

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

        supportActionBar?.hide()
...
```

and it works, however, I need to make this call from fragment, so I do it like this

```
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar!!.hide()

    }
```

and the result is

[image]

The action bar became kind of invisible instead of gone (you see this gray pass right under the clock)

What am I missing here?

**UPD**

I would like to add explanation to the problem, in order to illustrate this I did such code:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
        
        Thread {
            Thread.sleep(8000)

            mainExecutor.execute {
                supportActionBar?.show()      <---- 2
            }
        }.start()

        Thread {
            Thread.sleep(12000)

            mainExecutor.execute {
                supportActionBar?.hide()     <---- 3
            }
        }.start()

        supportActionBar?.hide()          <---- 1
...
```

What is happening here is - the method marked `1` is invoking first and the actionbar hides as expected. The next method #2 invokes `show()` for the action bar and the action bar appears as expected, however, when it comes to method #3 and tries to hide the actionbar again the bug is here. Instead of hiding the actionbar it kind of makes it invisible and you can see a grey line (like on the screenshot).

So, looks like it is possible to hide the actionbar only immediately in `OnCreate()` method if you try to do it after you will see a grey line instead of the actionbar.

**UPD**

My `MainActivity.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/awl_application_drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/main_activity_layout_bg_color"
    tools:openDrawer="end">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <application.widget.toolbar.BondToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/errorViewContainer"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_layout"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            style="@style/AppTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_nav_tab_height"
            android:background="@color/deprecated_palette_FF000000"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:padding="0dp"
            app:tabPaddingBottom="0dp"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
            app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
            app:tabPaddingTop="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:tabMinWidth="@dimen/bottom_nav_tab_min_width" />

        <CustomView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tab_layout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73293015/15754377

Comment: @VivekGupta this would be ok in case if each fragment has its own action bar implementation (or BaseFragment), however, in my case action bar is part of the Activity

Comment: Nope, actionBar is in activity and BaseFragment is calling activity's method to hide actionBar Or Fab. By making a BaseFragment, we remove boilerplate code   for each fragment

Comment: @VivekGupta, my bad, you are right, however, what is a diff with my approach `(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar!!.hide()` (described in the question) where actually I am trying to do the same I just call `hide()` method directly from the fragment...

Comment: @Sirop4ik can you show your activity layout.xml?

Answer (score 2):

When navigating to TestFragment, do `supportActionBar?.hide()` from Activity.
Do `supportActionBar?.show()` from Activity when navigating to the Fragment where the ActionBar should be visible.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something like this in a project but on an Activity but you can do the similar thing on Fragments also

Here I've created a method called "setupToolbar" which I call from onCreate right after setContentView(R.layout.___)

```
private fun setupToolbar() {
    toolbar.title = ""
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    toolbar.navigationIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.arrow_back_white_24)
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
        finish()
    }
    supportActionBar?.hide()
}
```

Then I added a gesture listener and observing SingleTap

```
private var gestureListener: GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener =
    object : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        override fun onSingleTapUp(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            if (toolbar.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
                supportActionBar?.hide()
                return true
            } else {
                supportActionBar?.show()
            }
            return false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be two options here.

- Defining topbar in each fragment layout and don't include in specific fragment where not required, rather than including in activity.

OR

- Define some NO ACTION BAR styles in style.xml, then set/unset it in java/kotlin code, when navigating to/from some fragment.

In styles.xml :

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

In kotlin/java code from activity:

Call setTheme method with above defined style and then call recreate()